# Index Entities without direct relation in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, denormalization

I'm trying to use Hibernate Search on two Entities, that do not (and must not) share a relation on object-level, however they're connected by a join table that uses their IDs. (legacy)

These are more or less the two Entities:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
class Person {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Field
    private String name;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Indexed
class Address {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Field
    private String street;

    @Field
    private String zip;
    ....
}
```

They are connected by their IDs:

```
@Entity
class Relation {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private long personId;
    private long addressId;
}
```

The goal I'm trying to achieve is finding similar persons that share a similar address via Hibernate Search. This means I'm searching for attributes from both Person and Address.

I guess the easiest way is to "emulate" an @IndexedEmbedded relation which means denormalizing the data and add "street" and "zip" from Address to a Person document. I stumbled upon Hibernate Search Programmatic API, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go (and how to go on from to there)..
Would this be the proper way of doing things or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot add this relationship into the model, you will be pretty much out of luck. You are right that you would have to index the `Person` and corresponding `Address` data into the same document (this is what `@IndexedEmbedded` does really). The normal/best way to customize the `Document` is via a custom (class) bridge. The problem in your case, however, is that you would need access to the current Hibernate `Session` within the implementation of the custom bridge.

Unless you are using some approach where this `Session` for example is bound to a `ThreadLocal`, there won't be a way for you to load the matching `Address` data for a given `Person` within the bridge implementation.